# Howto run mod-mono and php on same apache webserver

Tags: apache, php-7.2, mod-mono, centos8

I've successfully implemented mod-mono and apache webserver on a Centos 8 distro.
I've also installed PHP 7.2 on the server and the configuration looks ok on eye inspection.
However, the webserver is not executing the PHP files, but serving them for download.

If i go to http://example.com - it runs the website in MONO space
If I go to http://example.com/info.php - it gives me the PHP file for downloading. It makes me think that it tries to run the php file through mono and fails, so gives it to me for download instead forwarding it to PHP for execution.

Is it possible to run both PHP and MONO code on same apache webserver?
If yes, what could be the tricks to have it working ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually having a separate PHP website and also MONO websites in same apache server was working. However I though things were not working since I tried to run the PHP file from within the MONO-handled virtualhost ... so no need for clarifications.